# Filter a string and store in array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a one string.

> $a = '[{"size":"6Y","quantity":15}]';

I want to store 6Y and 15 in array.
Please help me.

Comment: Is there any your tried code ?

Comment: yes, I want to try this code

Comment: @student add your code to question.. not in comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

You have a json encoded string.

And need to decode it and assign size and quantity to an array.

**Working example:**

```
<?php
$a = '[{"size":"6Y","quantity":15}]';
$b = json_decode($a, TRUE);
$c = array();
if (! empty($b[0])) {
    foreach ($b[0] as $k => $v) {
        $c[$k] = $v;        
    }
}
echo '<pre>';print_r($c);echo '</pre>';
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [size] => 6Y
    [quantity] => 15
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) with [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

1. Json decode your string
2. Flatten the array

like this:

```
<?php
$a = '[{"size":"6Y","quantity":15}]';
$b = call_user_func_array('array_merge', json_decode($a,true));
print_r($b);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [size] => 6Y
    [quantity] => 15
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, use json_decode:

```
<?php
$a = '[{"size":"6Y","quantity":15}]';
$a = substr($a, 1, -1);
print_r((array)json_decode($a));
?>
```

Comment: Please check if your answer is working or not before posting it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = '[{"size":"6Y","quantity":15}]';
$v = json_decode($a);
print_r(array_values($v));
```